# Meteor countdown timer jquery not updating

Tags: jquery, meteor

Countdown timer in jquery not updating when we update in Meteor.The function written in the helper.Please find the bellow code.

```
var countdown =  setInterval(function()
        {
            $("#getting-started" + id).countdown(newdate, function (event) 
            {
                if (Number(event.strftime('%D')) < 2) {
                    $("#getting-started" + id).addClass('timerred');
                }
                else {
                    $("#getting-started" + id).addClass('timergreen');
                }

                $("#getting-started" + id).text
                (
                    event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
                );
            });
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'timer in jquery not updating when we update in Meteor', what are your updating in Meteor here?

Comment: We are updating the date@Matthisk

Comment: putting that in helper is not the smartest idea

Comment: can please tell me the better idea to update@AdamWolski

Comment: I am tryied in the document.ready function but not works@AdamWolski

Comment: You're trying to use jQuery patterns in Meteor where doing it in Meteor is so much simpler. Try the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package and just create a reactive time variable in your `onCreated` handler and simply display it.

Comment: @vamsikr Put it in the rendered callback for the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you need to understand is that, putting this code of code in the helper is not reliable, because it can re-run easily.

Putting the code in document.ready won't work also, because the way meteor handle the templates.

If you're depending on the DOM in specific template, the only way to be sure it exists is to put the code into `rendered` callback.

So assuming that you have template like that:

```
<template name="countdown">
    <div id="clock"></div>
</template>
```

the code you provided should land in the rendered callback of this template, so:

```
Template.countdown.rendered = function() {
//initiate the clock... and then
    var countdown =  setInterval(function()
        {
            $("#getting-started" + id).countdown(newdate, function (event) 
            {
                if (Number(event.strftime('%D')) < 2) {
                    $("#getting-started" + id).addClass('timerred');
                }
                else {
                    $("#getting-started" + id).addClass('timergreen');
                }

                $("#getting-started" + id).text
                (
                    event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
                );
            });
        }, 1000);
}
```

And another hint: if you're using the same selector for getting jquery object ("#getting-started" + id) execute it once, and assign to local variable, it is quicker, because you don't traverse DOM every time.